# Ternary Condition on ngClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

i am trying to toggle functionality depending on type of device. I have a setting tab as clickable. In desktop version, ngClick should redirect to default url. However, in mobile version the same link click would open a modal.
I did something like this

settings.Html -

```
 <li id="btn-alerts" ng-click="showSettingsModal ? openModal() : redirectToURL()">
```

settings.directive -

```
        $scope.showPharmacySettingsModal = false;
        if (deviceWidth < 481) {       
            currentDevice = 'mobile';
            $scope.showSettingsModal = true;
        }
        $scope.redirectTo = function(){
         $window.location.href = url;
        }
```

I was wondering if this a good way to check device and perform some action on ng-click. Is there any better way suggestable?

Thanks

Comment: Your logic should not be inside of the view, and you are missing a `:` in your ternary condition, between `openModal()` and `redirectToURL()`.

Comment: I would suggest to move the decision logic into the click handler function. And decide there if a modal should be opened etc.

Comment: @AlexanderBondar : thanks. Is it ok to check for innerwidth for checking device type?

Comment: Please check if the browsers you want to support, also support `.innerWidth`. Mostly I do checks this way: `window.innerWidth || $(document).width();` if jQuery is available.

Comment: I found a module that detects your device type in http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-device-detector. They also made a sample example in this  http://plnkr.co/edit/urqMI1 . I think this might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

ng-click is meant to work with a function. I'd suggest making a method on your scope that does what the ternary condition does and calling that in ng-click.

```
 <li id="btn-alerts" ng-click="chooseMethod()">
```

Then on your scope:

```
$scope.chooseMethod = function(){
      showSettingsModal ? openModal() : redirectToURL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-click="(AppliedApps!=null && Collapse('CollapsedAppliedApplications')) || (AppliedApps.length==0 && Collapse('CollapsedAppliedApplications'))">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.